# Fastlane Getting Freeze at Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' With azure Pipeline

Tags: ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, fastlane

[image]Using Fastlane with azure pipeline Build getting a freeze at **Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks** we aren't able to do further action on the build as it gets stuck on given a run script
Error:https://ibb.co/qFbqqfz

Also, raise the same query at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15290

Comment: Hi @SiddharthShah, Since you have got the solution from Github, do you mind convert it as answer then mark it? Thus it could help other SO users refer to it;-)

Comment: Hi @SiddharthShah, could you do what Merlin suggests? I don't really understand what you mean by your GitHub comment :(. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alright after some digging I've found the solution. My CI server was Travis, not Azure though.

With this setup you need to stop using Automatic code signing and select the `match` provisioning profile in your project settings.

Modify your **Fastfile** as follows:

```
before_all do |lane, options|
    ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"] = "travis-ci"
    ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"] = ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"]
end
```

Insert `create_keychain` before calling `sync_code_signing` (a.k.a `match`).

```
create_keychain(
    name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"],
    password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
    default_keychain: true,
    unlock: true,
    timeout: 3600,
    add_to_search_list: true
)
sync_code_signing(
    readonly: true,
    keychain_name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"],
    keychain_password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
)
```

Finally, remove the keychain with `delete_keychain` whenever appropriate, e.g. at the end of the lane.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Do you add this code inside the Fastfile.swift file in the function customLane()?

Comment: @RolandLariotte no you add this into your fastlane actions files. Not the `.swift` ones.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue only updated create_keychain like this:

```
create_keychain({
    name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"],
    password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
    default_keychain: true,
    unlock: true,
    timeout: 3600,
    add_to_search_list: true
})
```